# C#: Could anyone give me good example on how anchoring controls at runtime is done?

Tags: c#

C#: Could anyone give me good example on how anchoring controls at runtime is done?

Comment: Could you make yourself a bit more clear? 
Do you mean how to create new Controls and Add them to your Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        textBox1.Multiline = true;
        textBox1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

Then resize your form and the textbox should grow and shrink while maintaining the same distance from the form edges